# when is dart code executed in web app?

Tags: dart

If I have a HTML file with a `<script>` that links to my Dart program, when is my code executed? Specifically, when are the top level assignments executed, and when is `main()` function run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the dart documentation:](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/embedding-in-html/#dart-mime-type)

> The Dart app must have a visible top-level function called main(). The browser invokes main() when the DOM content is loaded (but see caveat in the next section).

[The caveat is:](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/embedding-in-html/#dart-html-semantics)

> The precise semantics of Dart execution on an HTML page are evolving and likely to change by the time Dart is natively supported in a production browser.
>
> Currently, your Dart app’s `main()` function is run after DOM content is loaded, but the exact timing is undefined (e.g., with respect to the load event or deferred JavaScript). In the future, we may invoke `main()` synchronously during HTML parsing instead of waiting for DOM content to load.

According to this tweet:

> [@caffinatedmonk](https://twitter.com/caffinatedmonk) top-level variables are lazily initialized. i.e. on their first access.
>
> — Seth Ladd (@sethladd) [March 10, 2014](https://twitter.com/sethladd/statuses/443099686455369728)

Variables are initialized the first time they are accessed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with top level assignments.

Top level fields and static fields are evaluated lazy
https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/JdLW-dE26Mw
https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/xYKqdcmnuBg

Comment: thanks. the link doe snot work for me. by top level assignments I mean , for example, the `final` values that you see at the top of the `sunflower` sample when you open it in the Dart editor. For instance, `final CanvasRenderingContext2D context = (querySelector("#canvas") as CanvasElement).context2D;`.